# NodeJs Csv parser async operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, async-await

I'm trying to read a csv file, fetch data for every record on csv do some operations and at the end (after all of the async operations are complete) write a new csv file here is the code:

```
async function readInputCsv() {

  results = [];
  fs.createReadStream('./example_short.csv')
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', async function(data){
        console.log("trying for name: ", data.username);
        let edu = await getLastEducation(data.username);
        results.push({
          name: data.username,
          level: edu
        })
        console.log(data.username,": ", edu)
}).on("end", () => {
  console.log("end ! ");
  writeCsv(results);

});
}
```

What happens is "end !" gets printed before the getLastEducation function returns the responses

Comment: Great solution is start to process data once read stream has been closed (on `end`).

Comment: That seems to work better thank you

Answer (score 0):

`fs.createReadStream().on()` does not accept Promises as second argument.

`on(event: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this;`

Comment: What should i do is there an alternative async/await syntax that could accomplish this

Comment: probably process data after you get result from `fs`

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `results` in this case is a global variable. I would suggest you to use `let` keyword to declare it within the scope of the function.

What is happening in this case is the time taken by the `getLastEducation()` for the async operation is more than the time required to the `example_short.csv` file.

To avoid this, add `await` keyword before `fs.createReadStream()` and move the `writeCsv()` function (I am assuming you are using `csv-writer` inside this function) after the entire read operation. The `await` keyword will make it wait until the async fetching operation is done.

```
async function readInputCsv() {
  let results = [];

  await fs
    .createReadStream('./example_short.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', async function (data) {
      console.log('trying for name: ', data.username);
      let edu = await getLastEducation(data.username);
      results.push({
        name: data.username,
        level: edu,
      });
      console.log(data.username, ': ', edu);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log('end ! ');
    });

  writeCsv(results);
}
```