# NodeJs csv-parse await inside on('data')

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, csv, node-csv-parse

I have a code, which reades .csv line by line and saves each parsed row to the database

```
const csv = require('csv-parse')
const errors = []
csv.parse(content, {})
    .on('data', async function (row: any) {
         const error = await tryToSaveToDatabase(row);
         if (error) {
            errors.push(error)
         }
     })
    .on('end', function () {
      // somehow process all errors
    })
```

but, unfortunately, `.on('end', ...` block is beeing called earlier then all `await` block succeded.

I have read [NodeJs Csv parser async operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302740/nodejs-csv-parser-async-operations) - seems we cannot use `await` inside `.on('data', ...` callback.

What is the correct way to perform such thing - if I want to read .csv line by line (files might be very huge - so it must be performed in a streaming manner) and collect some errors while saving to database? (these errors are displayed on frontend then)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63749853/possible-to-make-an-event-handler-wait-until-async-promise-based-code-is-done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://csv.js.org/parse/api/async_iterator/
This solution reads .csv line by line